# Passing Variable to scripts via SCCM

Tags: batch-file, sccm

I have a working batch script that executes an MSI on a set of servers and it accepts a conf file as part of its argument. Snippet:

```
msiexec /i xyz.msi /q confFile=x_conf.xml
```

There are different versions of the conf.xml file and the file that gets used depends on the target server. For example, y_conf.xml is used if we are executing the batch script on server y; the same applies for z_conf.xml and server z.

Question is, is it possible to use SCCM to dynamically pass the desired file for all 3 servers?

I have been told that I'd need to create a package for each pair of conf file and server, but I think there has to be a way to dynamically execute the same batch script with the corresponding conf file on the target server.

I am a newbie to SCCM so any pieces of advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the batch file is physically executing on the target server you should be able read the %computername% environmental variable to determine what configuration file to use.

Comment: Using environment variables like Squashman suggested is probably the only way to make it dynamic from the SCCM side but you could of course also not specify the conf file as parameter but use some logic inside the batch to figure out the files, thus making it dynamic via the batch file and not SCCM. As a side note: You would not need a package per server in any case you could use one package with 3 programs and using the same source (=batch file) for all 3 programs with different arguments

Comment: I ended up changing the design to have the batch execute on the target server, then used the %computername% ENV to determine the config. Thanks